# How to create a single 3 element collection list using three foreach loop in JAVA.?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

I want to create a single list which consist 3 elements, each one get value from 3 different foreach loop.

```
 for (WebElement webElement : li) {
        key = webElement.getText().trim().substring(10, 16) ;
  }
 //e.g {1,2,3,4,5,.......1000}

 for (String string : defectidList) {
        defectid =string;
  }
 //e.g {abc-1,abc-2,abc-3,abc-4,abc-5,......1000}
 for (WebElement element : hreflist) {
        hreflink =element.getText();
  }
 //e.g. {abc.com,bcd.com,def.com,abc.com,bcd.com,....1000}

 Class Pair{
  String key;
  String defectid;
  String hreflinks;

  Pair(String k,String d, String h){
  this.key=k;
  this.defectid=d;
  this.hreflinks=h;
  }
 }
ArrayList<Pair> pairlist = new ArrayList<Pair>
Pair p = new Pair(key,defectid,hreflinks)    
pairlist.add(p)
```

**How i should add each element from each loop so that i should get pairlist as**

```
1 abc-1 abc.com
2 abc-2 bcd.com
3 abc-3 def.com
4 abc-4 abc.com
5 abc-5 bcd.com
```

Comment: I assume the size of all three arrays/list are same

Comment: are the loops running on date structures which are already sorted (in the fashion you want them to be)?

Comment: @user3218114 yes size is same

Comment: @alihaider list has 1000 elements already stored in sorted order.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you just use the original `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { pairList.add(new Pair(list1.get(i), list2.get(i), list3.get(i))); }` like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the size of three lists are same, you could try omething like

```
for(int i=0;i<li.size();i++){
    ...
        Pair p = new Pair(
                li.get(i).getText().trim().substring(10, 16),
                defectidList.get(i),
                hreflink.get(i).getText()
                );
    ...
}
```

Null case handling ignored.

Answer (score 1):

How about a normal for loop?

```
ArrayList<Pair> = new ArrayList<Pair>;
for(int i = 0; i < li.length && i < defectidList.lengh && i < hrefList.length; i++){
    String key = li[i].getText().trim().substring(10, 16);
    String hrefLink = hrefList[i].getText();
    pairList.add(new Pair(key, defectidList[i], hrefLink));
}
```